# How do I undo a "setxkbmap pc"

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout

I inadvertantly executed `setxkbmap pc` instead of `setkxbmap us`. Apparently, this has the effect that the keyboard mapper now only(?) maps spaces and new lines. So, I cannot execute a `setxkbmap us` anymore, at least not in an Xterm.

Is there a way from recovering from this without exiting X?

Comment: Can you SSH into the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the mouse to copy/paste text into an xterm, probably a single character at a time, to run the `setxkbmap us` command. You could probably still open a web browser window to get some text from.